# Exception Handling with Spring's @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web app with Spring MVC and hibernate for persistence.
Given my DAO where GenericDao has a SessionFactory member attribute:

```
@Repository
public class Dao extends GenericDao {
    public void save(Object o) {
        getCurrentSession().save(o);
    }
}
```

And a Service class

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    Dao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Object o) {
        dao.save(o);
    }
}
```

I want to inform my user if a persistence exception occurs (constraint, duplicate, etc). As far as I know, the `@Transactional` annotation only works if the exception bubbles up and the transaction manager rolls back so I shouldn't be handling the exception in that method. Where and how should I catch an exception that would've happened in the DAO so that I can present it to my user, either directly or wrapped in my own exception?

I want to use spring's transaction support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring provides Exception Handlers.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

So you could have something like this in your controller to handle a ConstraintViolationException

```
  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public ModelAndView handleConstraintViolationException(IOException ex, Command command, HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    return new ModelAndView("ConstraintViolationExceptionView");
}
```

Comment: The issue with this that no exception (check or unchecked) escapes the service method annotated with `@Transactional`. It's caught internally and the transaction is rolled back. So you don't have access to it. I'm curious as if there is a way to get it while still using `@Transactional`

Comment: This only works if you use controllers. If you are processing a Kafka message, as an example, and not an HTTP request, this is useless

Answer (score 3):

After chasing around the issue for a while, I solved this by using an exception handler (as described in another answer) and the `rollbackFor` property of the `@Transactional` annotation:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

My exception handler is still called and writes the response accordingly, but the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: `@Transactional` will rollback for any unchecked exception. You only have to explicitly declare checked exceptions.

Comment: I realize now that I didn't make it clear that I was using an exception handler, which as you described in another comment in this thread, was problematic. I edited my answer to reflect that I used these two things in conjunction with one another to solve my problem.

Comment: No need to apologize. `Session#save` does not declare any checked exceptions, ie. it can't throw any checked exceptions. So in your scenario, you must have something else throwing checked exceptions which is why you need the `rollbackFor`.

Comment: I am throwing the exceptions, but adding an exception handler makes Spring commit. By adding the rollbackFor parameter, I was able to keep the exception handler but cause a rollback on exceptions, even if my handler handles them.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.